# Deleting field using cursor in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, fields-attributes, delete

Is there any way to use a cursor to delete a field using ArcPy?

I understand there are ways to use a cursor to delete records but I'm looking for a way to delete a field using a cursor.

Comment: To delete a field you want arcpy.DeleteField_management https://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000004n000000 but you can't do that with an active cursor because it locks the table.

Comment: @MichaelStimson I know that arcpy.DeleteField_management is an option but I was wondering if there is a way to achieve the same result with a cursor

Comment: @SonofaBeach I'm looking to delete the field from the table all together

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.  You cannot use a cursor to delete a field from the schema of a table or feature class.

Cursors are used to view or edit data, not to alter the schema.

As @MichalStimson commented, you will need to use `arcpy.DeleteField_management()` to delete a field, and this cannot be done while there is an active cursor due to the cursor's lock on the table.

See:  [Search Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/searchcursor-class.htm), [Update Cursor](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/data-access/updatecursor-class.htm), [Delete Field](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/delete-field.htm)